# LibGDX: rendering tiled-maps from tile to tile

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a problem with tiled-maps.

I must to render every tile in one of the layers tile-by-tile (from tile to tile).

How can I realize it?

I tried it, but it renders nothing.

```
private void drawObject(boolean down)
{
    final String objects = "objects";
    for (MapObject obj : world.getMap().getLayers().get(objects).getObjects())
    {
        if (!down)
        {
            if ((Integer) obj.getProperties().get("y") > world.getPlayer().getBody().getPosition().y)
            {
                world.getTiledMapRenderer().renderObject(obj); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to render an object layer. In order to render objects from the object layer, you need some other input for example:

```
for (MapObject mo : map.getLayers().get("Enemies").getObjects()) {      
        Enemy e = new Enemy(new Sprite(new Texture("maps/snailWalk1.png")), (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get(0));
        e.setPosition(((RectangleMapObject)mo).getRectangle().getX(), ((RectangleMapObject)mo).getRectangle().getY());
        enemies.add(e);
    }
```

And in your renderer method do like this:

```
renderer.render();

renderer.getSpriteBatch().begin();
    for (Enemy e : enemies) {
        e.draw(renderer.getSpriteBatch());
    }
```

As for the renderer you use a OrthonogalTiledMapRenderer or an IsometricTiledMapRenderer object. You should declare this as a class object

```
OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
```

If you want to do is render a layer tile-by-tile, I would say that you should take another approach, and try to make this layer as an object layer, and then create objects programitcally out of these.

Comment: Oh, is it possible to do without texturing in code?

Comment: No - with an object layer you need textures in your code AFAIK